# Thread dump at removeAll()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump, jstack

I have one button that remove existing JPanel and add new JPanel.
However my program will hang when I press that button.
I used jstack to trace and find that programs stuck at removeAll()

These are the relevant thread dump :

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x000000000df7f000 nid=0x394 runnable [0x000000002752a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Thread.holdsLock(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.checkTreeLock(Component.java:1199)
    at java.awt.Component.getOpaqueShape(Component.java:9804)
    at java.awt.Container.getOpaqueShape(Container.java:4066)
    at java.awt.Component.calculateCurrentShape(Component.java:9892)
    at java.awt.Component.applyCurrentShape(Component.java:9925)
    at java.awt.Container.recursiveApplyCurrentShape(Container.java:4132)
    at java.awt.Container.recursiveApplyCurrentShape(Container.java:4111)
    at java.awt.Component.applyCurrentShapeBelowMe(Component.java:9943)
    at java.awt.Component.mixOnHiding(Component.java:10003)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Container.mixOnHiding(Container.java:4265)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Component.removeNotify(Component.java:7027)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2816)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4771)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2800)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4771)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2800)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4771)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2800)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4771)
    at java.awt.Container.removeNotify(Container.java:2800)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.removeNotify(JComponent.java:4771)
    at java.awt.Container.removeAll(Container.java:1290)
    - locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at com.james.Dev.Dev$5.run(Dev.java:945)
    at com.james.guiUtil.SwingUtils$1.run(SwingUtils.java:485)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.axi.guiUtil.BusyCancelDialog.setVisible(BusyCancelDialog.java:136)
    at com.james.gui.Dev.Dev.populateWithProjectData(Dev.java:999)
    at com.james.gui.Dev.Dev.start(Dev.java:1910)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I have limited knowledge about analyzing thread dump but I did some study.

By `locked <0x0000000089600fd0> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)`

does it mean AWT-EventQueue-0 is holding those component? If yes then why wouldn't AWT-EventQueue-0 remove the component as it "owns" the component and is in runnable state ? thanks !

Comment: Does *your* code create any threads?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty.

Comment: Then I suspect this nasty error is caused by one of those threads [accessing the UI] ..

Comment: Can you post your action handler for the button? The lock is happening when a `Dialog#setVisible` and doesn't seem to be in your handler.